# Post Commit Email in Windows Server

Tags: windows, svn, post-commit-hook

I am currently working on a project that requires the use of SVN on Windows. I am keen to set up a post-commit hook so that any changes to the codebase is emailed out to all relevant users that the repository has changed.

Running a post-commit hook in Linux is pretty straight forward, and well documented, but I am struggling to find a good guide to doing this on a windows server.

Does anyone have a link to a guide that solves this problem, or have a set of steps that I can pass on to our server team to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install VisualSvn Server and use their [email hook](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/). They've pretty much done what you need already.
If not, the same hook should work - you might have to install perl or python to run your exising hook code, you should be able to send an emial once you have a client - even if that's [Outlook](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/sending-email-without-client.html), or [IIS SMTP Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193685) - or use a FOSS smtp client which will probably be more familiar to you.